# Where can I get a free engine to play Hexagonal Chess?

Tags: engines, chess-variants, hexagonal-chess

[This question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/what-are-the-rules-of-glinskis-hexagonal-chess) asks about the rules for Glinski's hexagonal chess. If I want to play a game of Glinski's hexagonal chess against the computer where can I get a free downloadable engine?

Answer (score 3):

[This page](https://www.chessvariants.com/link2.dir/hexodus.html) on the chess-variants website has links to various hexagonal chess playing engines. I particularly like Hexodus which you can [download from this link](https://www.chessvariants.com/programs.dir/Hexodus.zip).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a well implemented hexagonal chess app for mobile, [**Chexx**](https://play-chexx.web.app), quite intriguing, it implements Glinski's hexagonal chess variant just like Hexodus, also has online, friend invite and multiple (16) AI to play with. Give it a try.