# Opening Theory in Hexagonal Chess?

Tags: opening, theory, chess-variants, hexagonal-chess

Is there any opening theory in Glinski's hexagonal chess ([rules here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/what-are-the-rules-of-glinskis-hexagonal-chess/40975#40975))? If so what are some standard openings?

Comment: I know I am not supposed to ask for help in the answers but I just created account and cannot leave a comment to your own answer so please sorry. Can you please share some more theory? At least for these openings you named. It would be essential for me since I have been searching for the same book online for literally two days and found completely nothing.I would very much appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

I tracked down a book, *First Theories of Hexagonal Chess* by W Glinski published by Hexagonal Chess Publications in 1974 and managed to buy a second hand copy. That lists several openings:

1. King's Gambit Accepted
2. King's Gambit Declined
3. King's Knight Opening
4. Rook's Opening
5. Queen's Flank Opening
   6.King's Flank Opening
6. Four Pawn Opening
7. Centre Pawn Opening
8. Queen's Pawn Opening
9. Knight's Opening

Here are the moves given for:
**King's Gambit Accepted**

1. g6 fg 2. Nhf3 Be9 3. Nik5 Rig8 4. Bxk7
   (2... h6 3. Bi6+ NxB (3... Bh8 4. BxB+ RxB 5. Qxk7) 4. QxN Bh8 5. Ql4 Rh9)
   (2... Ng9 3. Bd4 e6 4. Nxg6)
   (2... Bd6 3. Bi5 Ng9 4. Bl4 Rg8 5. Bxg6 Qd8)
   (2... g5 3. fg Ng9 4. Bd4 e6 5. Rg3)