# Hexagonal Chess Puzzle - Black to play and win

Tags: puzzles, hexagonal-chess

[image]

Published in Hex Press 4 - September 1977 and taken from the game Armstrong vs Springgay

Reminder of the rules [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/what-are-the-rules-of-glinskis-hexagonal-chess/40975#40975).

**Hint 1**: If black could lure the white queen to g7 then Ne5+ would discover an attack on the white queen.

**Hint 2** Bi6g7+ forks the white queen and king but is answered by Nk5xBg7. White is not forced to play QxBg7

Answer (score 1):

As hint 2 suggests *Bi6g7+ forks the white queen and king but is answered by Nk5xBg7* so the Nk5 has to be taken first - Bh9xNk5. White has to retake with the bishop on f1 or be a piece down. Then black can decoy the white queen to g7 by playing the fork Bi6-g7+. After the queen takes the bishop Ne5+ uncovers an attack on the white queen from the black queen.

Here are the moves in full:

1...Bh9xNk5
2. Bf1xNk5 Bi6-g7+
3. Qxg7 Ne5+
4. f5xN QxQ

leaving black up a queen for two pieces.